# Add data persistence in hyperledger fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I have built a hyperledger fabric network. The below is the configuration right now in my `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
    environment:
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_example
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
      - peer0.org1.example.com:/var/hyperledger/production
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    networks:
      - example

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - example
```

I have missed on adding the configuration for data persistence. 
I am following this [documentation link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/build_network.html?highlight=couchdb%20data%20persistence#a-note-on-data-persistence)  to add data persistence. 
So after I add below line in `fabric-couchdb` it will use the host machine's specified file system for storing data.

```
volumes:
 - /var/hyperledger/couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data
```

But the thing that I am not able to figure out is how do we retrieve the current data that is present in the network now. Where does `fabric-couchdb` stores data by default? Can we not copy the old data from default folder location to new folder location?

Comment: This is the default location for the couchdb container and all the data persists in this directory: /opt/couchdb/data. Yes you can copy the data of couchdb from this directory.

Comment: `/opt/couchdb/data` this path does not exists in the host machine. If I do `docker exec -it couchdb0 bash` then I can see files are present under the path `/opt/couchdb/data`. But where can I find the same files in the host machine? NOTE: I haven't done the directory mapping in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: If you haven't done directory mapping then it won't be in the host machine and will only be inside docker container. But you can copy that data using docker cp command as given by @kekomal in the answer below. And after you add the above specified volume then the data from now onwards will get updated in your host machine in this path: /var/hyperledger/couchdb0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the CouchDB volume as you say, your host folder should be in `/var/hyperledger/couchdb0`.

You can always run `docker volume ls` and `docker volume inspect your_volume_name` to check the mount point of your volumes.

If you have not defined volumes for your container and you want to retrieve the folder (I think that's your problem), then try:

```
docker cp couchdb0:/opt/couchdb/data your-host-destination-folder
```